# C# Appending nodes to an existing XML (contains) namespace but new nodes get blank namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, appendchild, xmlnode

I am having an XML which contains the following namespace:

```
<AUTOSAR xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/3.1.4 autosar_3-1-4.xsd" xmlns="http://autosar.org/3.1.4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

I have written the code to append nodes a particular level in the XML file, everything is working fine but for the node that I 1st create, it adds, For ex:  < FUNCTION-NAME-VALUE **xmlns=""**> (the part in the bold text) . I want this tag to have the namespace as all the other tags in the XML, but this is the extra part that is automatically generated when a new node is created. How to approach this issue.
Ps: I have not declared any namespace in my C# code.

This is the part of XML I'm trying to append:

```
<FUNCTION-NAME-VALUE>
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="FUNCTION-NAME-DEF">/AUTOSAR/Com/ComConfig/ComSignal/ComInvalidNotification</DEFINITION-REF>
    <VALUE>Rte_COMCbkInv_EPS_SteeringTorque</VALUE>
</FUNCTION-NAME-VALUE>
```

This is the issue I'm facing:

```
<FUNCTION-NAME-VALUE xmlns="">
    <DEFINITION-REF DEST="FUNCTION-NAME-DEF">/AUTOSAR/Com/ComConfig/ComSignal/ComInvalidNotification</DEFINITION-REF>
    <VALUE>Rte_COMCbkInv_EPS_SteeringTorque</VALUE>
</FUNCTION-NAME-VALUE>
```

Of all these tags that I'm creating, only the 1st tag is getting that **xmlns:""** issue.

This is the C# code written to create these nodes:

```
if (funChilds[m].InnerText != "/AUTOSAR/Com/ComConfig/ComSignal/ComNotification")
{
    XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateElement("FUNCTION-NAME-VALUE");
    XmlNode defNode_func = doc.CreateElement("DEFINITION-REF");
    XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("DEST");
    attr.Value = "FUNCTION-NAME-DEF";
    defNode_func.Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr);
    defNode_func.InnerText = "/AUTOSAR/Com/ComConfig/ComSignal/ComInvalidNotification";
    XmlNode valNode_func = doc.CreateElement("VALUE");
    valNode_func.InnerText = ("");
    newNode.AppendChild(defNode_func);
    newNode.AppendChild(valNode_func);
    def_ref[j].AppendChild(newNode);
}
```

Please let me know the necessary changes that are to be made to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

If namespace is specified for the newly created element, the problem of blank namespaces can be resolved!

```
 XmlNode defNode_func = doc.CreateElement("DEFINITION-REF", "NamespaceURI");
```